# Can I collapse content spread across two displays to a unique space for each display when the 2nd display is removed?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, spaces, window-manager

I use two displays at work and then I unplug my 2nd display when I go on the road/home.  It's an incredible shortcoming that all my content on the 2nd display gets squished so it's mostly off screen when I unplug the second display and revert to just the Macbook display.  It's also cumbersome to always be dragging windows around.  Is there a way to use one "space" but spread across two displays when I have two available but then when there is only one available collapse the content that I have on the second display to a second "space"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried that specifically, but after trying out pretty-much every window-position-remembering app out there, I found that only [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) actually did what I wanted.

It lets one save the window configuration for each display configuration, and seems to be Spaces-aware.

I have nothing to do with them, but thought they provided something useful.

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for.  I'll try it out.

Comment: As a side note, I've also found that Cinch and SizeUp from [Irradiated Software](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/) make your life incredibly easier.

Comment: Works wonderfully! Entirely worth the $15 (but you can install and play with it w/o paying).